# Using rsync through intermediate host with `sudo` on jump-host

Tags: ssh, rsync, sudo

I am `user1@host1` and would like to transfer data via `rsync` from `user3@host3`. However, I can access `host3` only via `user3@host2`. The catch is, that I can become `user3` on `host2` only via `su` or `sudo`, but have to connect to `host2` as `user2`.

So in order to login to `host3` on the shell I execute:

```
user1@host1 $ ssh user2@host2
user2@host2 $ su user3
user3@host2 $ ssh host3
user3@host3 $ # done!
```

My attempts to encapsulate all this in a (single) call to `rsync` lead to the following:

```
rsync -a -e "ssh -A user2@host2 'sudo -u user3 ssh'" host3:/... /...
```

Unfortunately, `requiretty` is set in `/etc/sudoers` on `host2`, so this results in the message: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

I can add `-tt` to the ssh call:

```
rsync -a -e "ssh -tt -A user2@host2 'sudo -u user3 ssh'" host3:/... /...
```

In which case I get: `protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?`. Apparently, there is some output on `host2`'s TTY that causes rsync to fail. I have no control over either that output or `/etc/sudoers`.

Is there any way I can do this, maybe using `ProxyCommand` or SSH tunnels?

---

Using this `simplescript.sh` it works:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user2@host2 "su user3 -p -c 'ssh $@'"
```

Then with `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -e './simplescript.sh' pmtlnx009.wob.vw.vwg:/tmp/t19 /tmp/t19
```

That is fine, I guess; it would be nice, though, to integrate the script into the CLI call.

Comment: Is this because user3 has some different SSH keys?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I would rather not install new/different SSH keys anywhere.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` in all your inline commands but `su -c` in the script? Any other unusual sudo configuration besides requiretty? (And is the system configured for passwordless `su`?)

Comment: I tried with `su -c` but somehow wasn't able to make the command work. su works passwordless because user2 is actually root.

Comment: If user2 is root, can you skip the `sudo`, and just use user3's private key directly with something like `ssh -i /home/user3/.ssh/id_rsa ...`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Unfortunately the homes are on a network share where root has no access. So changing user is necessary...